# Efficient computation of a product of $3$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

Let $U\in\Bbb{R}^{d\times n}$, such that $U^\top U=I_n$, where $I_k$ denotes the identity matrix of order $k$. Also, let $A\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix. The following product must be computed:
$$
T = UAU^\top\in\Bbb{R}^{d\times d}.
$$
Is there any efficient way for doing so? I am looking for a pseudocode, as I want to implement it in some low-level language ($\texttt{C}$), but without using some linear algebra library (e.g. GLS, etc.).

**Edit:**
As an additional comment, let the eigen decomposition of $A$ be known. That is,
$$
A = P\Lambda P^\top,
$$
where $P$ is an $n\times n$ orthonormal matrix consisting of the eigenvectors of $A$, and $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ is the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $A$. Actually, you can assume that $P$ is the matrix created by keeping the first $d$ columns of $U$ followed by transpose operator on it.

Thanks you very much!

Comment: For what it's worth, necessarily $d=n$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am not sure I understand why... What do you mean by ``necessarily''?

Comment: I mean that $\left(UU^T=I_d\land U^TU=I_n\right)\implies d=n$. This is a consequence of $\text{rank}(XY)\leq \min\left(\text{rank}(X),\text{rank}(Y)\right)$.

Comment: You are right. So, I was not careful about that. What if we just follow the assumptions of my additional comments below? I mean that, if $U$ is created by $P$ by keeping the first $d$ columns (eigenvectors), and by taking the transpose next? That wouldn't mean that $U^\top U=I_n$?

Comment: There seems to be something not quite right with the edit either, you mention the SVD, but then you provide a diagonalization. These decompositions don't coincide in general. Then you seem to be relating $P$ to $A$ to $U$, but there's no relation between $A$ and $U$ in the question.

Comment: @nullgeppetto if you keep the first $d$ **columns**, then your matrix $U$ should be $n \times d$.  The resulting matrix would satisfy
$$
U^TU = I_d
$$

Comment: Apologies... I need to make some corrections here... So, @GitGud, you are right, I just take the eigen decomposition of $A$ (not SVD), I will edit it. Also, Omnomnomnom, after keeping the first $d$ columns (which indeed results in an $n\times d$ matrix), I take the transpose of it; so $U\in\Bbb{R}^{d\times n}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose 
$$
\Lambda = \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\lambda_2\\&&\ddots\\&&&\lambda_n}
$$
Furthermore, suppose that $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, and that $U$ is the matrix consisting of the first $d$ columns of $P$.  We then have
$$
U^T\Lambda U[i,j] = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k U[k,i] U[k,j] 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose that the same holds for the case that $R=U^\top\in\Bbb{R}^{d\times n}$. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that your answer is not consistent. I mean that, based on what you say, $U\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times d}$. Right? Is there any chance you mean what I mean above? That $Ud\times n$? Thanks again!

Comment: All right! That's exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks!

Comment: see my latest edit; I had a few things wrong before

Comment: Thanks again! I love MathSE, I learned a lot of useful things, just by asking that simple question!